# Zend 1.12 Mail CC multiple recipients with same name

Tags: php, zend-framework

In one of our project, we are sending mails to users using Zend SMTP. The Zend version is 1.12.

We use the addCC function for sending copy of mails to a set of users. Two of the users are having same name but different email address. When we pass the recipient array to addCC function, the mail is going to only one of the user.

zend excepts the cc user list in the form of

```
$ccListArray = array('name1'=>'email1','name2'=>'email2','name3'=>'email3')
$mail->addCc($ccListArray);
```

When we have 2 users with same name, the first entry gets overwritten.

I can add each users individually, but we are sending hundreds of mails every day and looping the CC list is always not feasible.

Is there any other way i can add all mails to CC list at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys of an array must be unique.
May be you can try something like this:

```
$ccListArray = array(['name' => 'name1', 'email' => 'email1'],
                     ['name' => 'name2', 'email' => 'email2'],
                     ['name' => 'name3', 'email' => 'email3']);
foreach($ccListArray as $cc){
    $mail->addCc($cc['email'], $cc['name']);
}
```

Comment: But then the name will not correct right? I know the problem is with array due to the same keys. My question was will zend accepts the CC list apart from adding it individually

Comment: I have mentioned about this solution in my question already, "I can add each users individually, but we are sending hundreds of mails every day and looping the CC list is always not feasible. "

Comment: you said :"I can add each users individually, but we are sending hundreds of mails every day and looping the CC list is always not feasible. ". OK, but the `addCc()` method loop the CClist. (look the Zend/Mail.php).

Comment: ok doydoy44. I have not checked that zend library file. Since i have no other way to do this, i am doing it using the individual addCC method. Thanks for your time and i accepted your answer.